# in local PHPExcel save() working fine, but in server not creating xls file?

Tags: phpexcel

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$objWriter->save("test.xls");
```

PHPExcel save() not working in server ?

but working fine local machine?

anything i am missing?

Comment: Is there a PHP error? Or is the file just not being created?

Comment: Are you sure php-interpreter on server has enough rights to write files in that directory? Try `touch("test.xls");` to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Are the rights on the folder you are writing to sufficient enough to create or modify files? Use **`CHMOD`** to change the rights.

When using **`error_reporting(E_ALL)`** are there any errors or warnings?
Production servers often have display_errors set to off, turn it on by using **`ini_set("display_errors", "on")`** to display them for your test file.

Comment: file not creating and shows no error. how can use chmod() to that xls file? can u give me example?

Comment: chmod("/images/original", 0777); something like this??

Comment: Use Chmod on the folder you are trying to write your file to. For example: `chmod("temp", 0777);` and use this folder for saving the file: `$objWriter->save("temp/test.xls");` The folder (temp) for this example has to be placed on the same level as the file you are executing.

Comment: thanks for ur support, It was in production server,  I did same thing, but it was not resolve my issue,

Comment: mine, create a file and download it. but can't open in office program. but work fine on windows with xampp. does this have issue with linux as server ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Use ob_end_clean() function before $objWriter->save("test.xls");

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save("test.xls");
```